# how to get before and after date from the given date?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table as below,

| empno | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-08-20 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 2022-08-19 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 2022-08-18 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 2022-08-17 00:00:00 |

If the date is 2022-08-22 I want to get 2022-08-20 00:00:00 as my output. How can I get this?

Thank you.

Comment: What if the input value is 2022-08-19? Do you want 2022-08-18 and 2022-08-20 and they are *before* and *after* respectively?

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. If you only want the rows around a certain date you can use `where date between @start and @end` and calculate the start and end dates DATEADD. If you want to get the row right before or right after another in an ordered result set you can use a ranking function like `ROW_NUMBER()` or `RANK()` and filter by it. You can get the next or previous value in an ordered result with `LEAD(somefield)` or `LAG(somefield)`

Comment: If you only want the *value*, MAX/MIN are enough, eg `select max(value) from ThatTable where date<=@cutoff` will give you the latest date before `@cutoff`